# Insufficient balance in bank account with stripe refund behavior

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-payment-intent

I have a question regarding stripe refund behavior.
Let's assume that a user requested a refund of amount 300$.

current Stripe balance =  100$
current Bank balance = 100$

I know our refund request will go into the pending state as we have an insufficient balance  but
Will stripe deduct these 200$ for now and 100$ for later? OR
stripe doesn't deduct these 200$ and will deduct 300$ as a whole when our account gets sufficient balance.

Comment: I don't know what the value limit is, but in my case I had no balance and there was a refund, leaving only negative -5, then when there was another value entry, it covered these 5, becoming positive again, I think the same thing would happen, but I don't know what the maximum value that can be negative

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but if you run `Stripe::Account.retrieve("acct_1IiKuy2fyHZdhpIy")` it might give account attributes like `debit_negative_balances":true` etc. Not sure if that answers your question though.

Comment: @Pimenta its means it goes in negative let me sure that with any doc , &  yes we are not sure what will be the maximum negative value.

Comment: I do not think Stripe has the ability to determine how much is in your external bank balance.  In that case they would submit the request to withdraw $200 from your account, be denied, and your refund would remain in the pending state.  At that point it would remain pending until you took action to add funds to your Stripe account. That is how I interpret this sentence "​​If Stripe can’t debit the remaining amount from your bank account, your refunds may go into a pending status until you add funds to your Stripe balance."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a specific question about stripe and they should ask support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this support FAQ](https://support.stripe.com/questions/pending-refunds-due-to-insufficient-funds-or-stripe-balance), your Stripe balance would be debited and go negative, but the refund would be `pending` until you topped up your account or collected more payments to restore your balance to positive.

You should contact Stripe support for more questions about this: https://support.stripe.com/contact